# Pausing cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a UIViewController and a UITableViewCell. And I am trying to pause UIViewController from running `cellForRowAtIndexPath` until a function that evaluates a Boolean is passed as true.

The reason that I want to pause the process is that I need a another process (HealthKit query -> CoreData Store -> CoreData fetch)  to complete before I push the data onto the Cell. Otherwise the cell will be empty

My code below give an error:

```
2014-12-30 11:39:21.235 Protocol Test Two[12013:862059] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:7344
```

**Question** How can I pause the "cell creation"?

```
func continuePopulatingCell () {

    notificationCount = notificationCount + 1

    if notificationCount == totalQueries {

            func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var myCell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as TableViewCell

                myCell.title.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
                myCell.imageName =  imageNameArray[indexPath.row]
                myCell.xAxisDates = xAxisDatesArray[indexPath.row]     
                myCell.yAxisValues = yAxisValuesArray[indexPath.row]   

            return myCell    
            }

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name:"ActivityIndicatorNotification", object:nil)
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is the wrong pattern. You don't pause cell creation, you put what you can on screen, start your longer-running operation in the background, then reload the relevant cells.

Comment: Ok, and how do I reload the cells?

Comment: ... Which, if you're using a fetched results controller linked to core data, will happen automatically.

Comment: You call 'self.tableView.reloadData()'

Comment: Great answers both - thanks! Why don't you make an answer instead of comment?

Comment: You've asked nine questions over the last couple of days, all clearly about the same project. Looking over them, I have to say you should be looking up and following some basic tutorials rather than coming here with every problem you face - you'll be able to ask better questions, and better understand the answers.

Comment: I haven't answered because the right answer is really "find out how core data, fetched results controllers and table views work together" which isn't really a very good answer :)

Comment: Thank you, I have taken the two most popular courses for Swift programming on Udemy. Taking a couple tutorials would not have helped me know that what I attempted in this question was the wrong pattern. You just don't learn that stuff in tutorials. It requires experience. Granted I could have figured out how to reload the cells. Either way I am thankful,  that this site saves me days of frustration in trying to figure out the solution to what is for you guys, a 10 seconds job. Thank you